# Efficient way to render tilemap

Tags: c#, xna, tiles, maps

I have set up a tilemap system, and am rendering it in a way that lets me pan through the map using a camera offset. However, I have discovered it is incredibly inefficient, but am unsure of how  I can increase efficiency.

Here is my current rendering code:

```
float lastCamOffSetX = -1, lastCamOffSetY = -1;

public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{       
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.Begin();

    int count = 0;

    int startCol = (int)camOffsetX/world.TileWidth;
    int startRow = (int)camOffsetY/world.TileHeight;
    int endCol = (int)(startCol + viewPortWidth - (camOffsetX/world.TileWidth));
    int endRow = (int)(startRow + viewPortHeight - (camOffsetY/world.TileHeight));

    if (startCol < 0) startCol = 0;
    if (startRow < 0) startRow = 0;

    if (endCol > world.Width) endCol = world.Width;
    if (endRow > world.Height) endRow = world.Height;

    for (int x = startCol; x < endCol; x++)
    {
        for (int y = startRow; y < endRow; y++)
        {
            int screenPosX = (int)((x * world.TileWidth) - (camOffsetX));
            int screenPosY = (int)((y * world.TileHeight) - (camOffsetY));

            Tile tile = world.Data[x, y];

            if (screenPosX >= -1 * world.TileWidth 
                && screenPosX <= (viewPortWidth + 1) * world.TileWidth
                && screenPosY >= -1 * world.TileHeight 
                && screenPosY <= (viewPortHeight + 1) * world.TileHeight)
            {
                Color color 
                    = (tile.TileType == TileType.Land ? Color.Green : Color.Blue);

                DrawRectangle(spriteBatch, new Rectangle(screenPosX, 
                    screenPosY, world.TileWidth, world.TileHeight), color);

                count++;
            } 
        }
    }

    //Debug.WriteLine(count + " - " + (endCol-startCol)*(endRow-startRow));

    spriteBatch.End();

    lastCamOffSetX = camOffsetX;
    lastCamOffSetY = camOffsetY;
}

private void DrawRectangle(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Rectangle coords, Color color)
{
    var rect = new Texture2D(this.GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
    rect.SetData(new[] { color });
    spriteBatch.Draw(rect, coords, color);
}
```

Currently, I am only drawing tiles which are inside the screen/camera region. How can I improve the efficiency of my script?

Comment: Looks like you are using XNA/MonoGame, maybe add the tag too.

Comment: Also what exact issue are you having? Is it slowing the game down, are you targetting 60fps and not getting anywhere near that?

Answer (score 1):

your DrawRectangle is the bottleneck. Creating a texture is a very very expensive operation. Create the texture first and than use the reference from it to draw it.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new texture every frame (and even worse, inside `Draw()` instead of `Update()`).

```
private void DrawRectangle(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Rectangle coords, Color color)
{
    var rect = new Texture2D(this.GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
    rect.SetData(new[] { color });
    spriteBatch.Draw(rect, coords, color);
}
```

You could create a more permanent variable to hold the texture and then reuse the texture over and over. Since you are using a color there are two ways about this.

Use a dictionary of sorts and cache a color when it comes across it and just create a new texture if the color does not already exist. This may be a bit overkill in this situation.

A better way would be to create the texture once and use `SpriteBatch` to tint it, you need to set your textures color to white, this can be done such as:

```
Texture2D rect = ... // do your new texture here. 1x1 and colored Color.White. 
// Create this ONCE! not inside Update or Draw loops.

public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Start of your drawing code

    Color color = GetColorLogicMethod(); // or your inline stuff above.
    spriteBatch.Draw(rect, coords, color); // This will tint the White 1x1 with the new color.

    // Rest of your drawing code
}
```

This way the expensive `new Texture2D()` and `Texture2D.SetData()` are only done once. The rest of your code looks like it should be pretty good as it is now for what you are doing.